# value of variable is not altered if changed in python-shell inside app.post of server.js file

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express

I have defined var x=6  but inside pyshell.on I change it , and print outside pyshell.on it still shows x being 6 .
Can anybody answer why and propose a solution so that my value changes.
Here is my code :

```
  console.log('email '+ req.body.email);
  console.log('width',req.body.widt);
  console.log('name with ext',req.body.email+'.'+req.body.fileExt)
  var x=6;
  let {PythonShell} = require('python-shell')
  var pyshell = new PythonShell('temp_file.py');



  pyshell.send(req.body.width); // permi error (tolerance)
  pyshell.send(req.body.email+'.'+req.body.fileExt); //image_NAME with (extension)
  pyshell.on('message', function (message) {
    console.log('result',message);  
    x=3;


  }); 
  console.log(x);

res.send([{name:'yobro',rollno:'743'},{name:'kyahas',rollno:'3324'}]);
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`pyshell.on` sets an event listener with a callback (the function you defined). Then, node executes the next statement, which is logging the value of x. At that time, the callback still hasn't triggered, so x is still 6.

It's not particularly clear why you need x to change or where you use it after it changes, and the solution will depend on how you use it afterwards.

Comment: yeah I got it ,I was trying to call res.send after the execution of python file , so that i could retrive all print messages . doing this solved my problem  pyshell.end(function (err,code,signal,res) {
     
        y();
        

    })
    function y(){
      res.send(results);
    }